# "is" and "id" in Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.5

i have questions:
I'm using python 3.5 , win7-32bit system.

Here's my code:

```
a=3
b=3
print(id(a))
print(id(b))
```

it returns:

```
1678268160
1678268160
```

So we could know that a and b reference to same object.

But here comes the question:

```
a=3
b=3
print( id(a) is id(b) )
```

It return :

```
False
```

I dont understand why this happened, I think it should be True.
Can anyone explain to me?
Thanks !

Comment: You can simplify the question to `print( id(a) is id(a) )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` returns a Python `int` object (the memory address of the object you're `id`-ing, though that's an implementation detail). But aside from very small `int`s (again, implementation detail), there is no `int` caching in Python; if you compute the same `int` two ways, it's two different `int` objects that happen to have the same value. Similarly, a fresh `int` is created on each call to `id`, even if the objects are the same.

The equivalence for `id` and `is` is that `a is b` implies `id(a) == id(b)`, not `id(a) is id(b)` (and in fact, since `id`s are large numbers, `id(a) is id(b)` is almost always `False`).

Also note, your test case is flawed in other ways:

```
a = 3
b = 3
a is b
```

only returns `True` for the `is` comparison because of the small `int` cache in CPython; if you'd done:

```
a = 1000
b = 1000
a is b
```

`a is b` would be `False`; your assumptions about identity only hold in CPython for numbers in the range -5 to 256 inclusive, which are singletons for performance reasons, but all other `int`s are recreated as needed, not singletons.

Comment: Wow, i've test your explained, it works!

Answer (score 1):

`id(a) is id(b)` compares the *ids of the ids returned by the `id` function*.

`id(a) == id(b)` will be `True` since the `a is b` and during an object's lifetime, the value returned by `id` will always be the same.  However, each time `id` is called, a distinct integer (that has the same value) is returned so `id(a) is id(b)` is `False`.